# Enqueing External JS on the remote server JS

Tags: php, functions, wp-enqueue-script

```
wp_register_script( 'custom-js', 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codexo/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.1', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js' );
```

Above is the **function** through which I am trying to enqueue an external javascript, but this is not working. where am I going wrong and how can I fix this?

Full code here:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'function_script' ) ) {

function function_script() {
        // Register the script like this for a theme:
        wp_register_script( 'custom-js', 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/codexo/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.1', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js' );


        wp_enqueue_style( 'styles', THEMEROOT . '/style.css' );
        // wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
        // wp_enqueue_style( 'responsive', THEMEROOT . '/css/responsive.css', array('styles'));
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','function_script');
```

Comment: Where did you put that code?

Comment: Full code updated.

Comment: I don't see any problem in there. Two problems that may occur: 1. There can be script with handle `custom-js` already registered. It won't get registered for the second time. 2. There may exist some other function called `function_script` on your site and it will be called instead of yours...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `$` in `custom.js` file and probably that's the reason, because jQuery is included in WordPress in **noConflict mode**.

You can replace `$` with `jQuery` in `custom.js` or wrap the code as shown below:

```
(function( $ ) {

    // --- your code ---
    $(document).ready(function() {
       //...
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Or

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // code from file whithout line "$(document).ready(function(){"
    //...

});
```

More about using jQuery in Wordpress you can read in ["JavaScript Best Practices"](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/javascript-best-practices/#using) on codex.

Comment: Yes you was right. This was the deal breaker: `jQuery(document).ready(function($)`

Comment: I will always remember this rest of my life now.